# SOQL: Compare result of Date Function with Date Literal in Where Clause

Tags: apex, soql, date

Say I have a query that goes something like this:

```
Currency_Exchange_Rates__c cerRec = [SELECT Currency_Code__c, Exchange_Rate_Period__c, Exchange_Rate__c
FROM Currency_Exchange_Rates__c 
WHERE Currency_Code__c = :c.Currency__c 
AND THIS_MONTH = CALENDAR_MONTH(Exchange_Rate_Period__c)
AND THIS_YEAR = CALENDAR_YEAR(Exchange_Rate_Period__c) LIMIT 1];
```

This returns an error:

> expecting a colon, found 'CALENDAR_MONTH'

A little research reveals that you **can't** actually compare the result of a Date function with a Date literal in the WHERE clause (see Notes at bottom of [this page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp))

So Salesforce has clearly documented that I can't do this, but I can't figure out how to work around this limitation? Seems like a pretty common use case - how can I best filter out SOQL records where I need to compare a date field to a current date?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in code I had previously written -_-

Rather than use SOQL's date literals like `TODAY`, instead use *Apex*
class functions that provide the same thing. In this case, I used a combination of the `today()`, `month()`, and `year()` functions of the Date class:

```
Currency_Exchange_Rates__c cerRec = [SELECT Currency_Code__c, Exchange_Rate_Period__c, Exchange_Rate__c 
FROM Currency_Exchange_Rates__c 
WHERE Currency_Code__c = :c.Currency__c 
AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Exchange_Rate_Period__c) = :Date.Today().month()
AND CALENDAR_YEAR(Exchange_Rate_Period__c) = :Date.Today().year()
LIMIT 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for specifically data

```
Date dte = CALENDAR_MONTH(Exchange_Rate_Period__c);

List<Account> acc = [Select Id, Name From Account Where CreatedDate =: dte ];
```

Let me know if you faced issue with this also.